# Compare database data with html table and refresh on change with AJAX in Laravel 8

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, eloquent

I have multiple columns in my database that I want to display in a dataTable.

Everytime some of that data changes I want the page to refresh.

Currently my AJAX code is looking like this:

```
<script>
let interval = 1000;

function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'listen/entries',
        data: {
            '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // console.log(data);
        },

        complete: function (data) {
            setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
        }
    });
}
let timeout = setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
```

And my controller sends JSON to the view with:

```
public function getEntries() {
    //
    return Entry::all()->toJson();
}
```

I don't want the page being refreshed only because of a change in row count, but also when for example a title changes or some other input.

My table is currently displaying all data with a @foreach loop inside the blade file. (I use a different function of my Controller than the one above).

Comment: what about using jquery or vuejs, both of them can solve your problem in their own way

Comment: I’m not really experienced with Vuejs, but I came across it a few times. What’s the best way to begin with vue?

Comment: try to use components, basically onChange() will solve the problem for you, you can use mounted() in vuejs but to do that with only js will end up writing a lot of code

Comment: you can either pass blade data to vue component or make a api call to backend for data, then update your table with each change at runtime, see this blog it would be helpful, https://medium.com/@offeilord/using-watch-on-dynamic-table-cells-in-vue-js-63721b0f3b4a

Comment: And a refreshing div, is that a possibility in my case?